# Create a new TLS certificate signed by an intermediate certificate using openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I have a trusted intermediate key and certificate (PEM files) that I own and I would like to create a certificate for my load balancer that is signed by it.

How is this done using openssl?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you already have your root key/cert pair files as follows:

```
.
root-cert.pem
root-key.pem
```

Here are the steps to generate a public facing certificate that you can use for your server.  First, create a new private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out my.key.pem 2048
```

Next, create a certificate signing request CSR with the new key:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key ./my.key.pem -out ./my.csr
```

Third, create your signed public certificate (valid for 1 year)!

```
openssl x509 -req -in my.csr -CA root-cert.pem -CAkey root-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out my.crt.pem -days 365 -sha256
```